# Old value when raising EditContext.OnFieldChange

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-editform

I have blazor app with version `5.0.11` of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly`.
I made following page and component:

```cs
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

```cs
@page "/"

<EditForm @ref="form" Model="vm">
    <select type="text" @onchange="HandleChange">
        <option label="Cat" value="Cat" />
        <option label="Dog" value="Dog" />
        <option label="Rat" value="Rat" />
    </select>
    <InputComponent @bind-Value="vm.Value"/>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private EditForm form;
    private readonly ViewModel vm = new();

    private void HandleChange(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        vm.Value = args.Value?.ToString();
        form.EditContext!.NotifyFieldChanged(FieldIdentifier.Create(() => vm.Value));
    }
}
```

```cs
@inherits InputBase<string>

<h3>@myValue</h3>

@code {
    private string myValue;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        EditContext.OnFieldChanged += (_, __) => myValue = Value;
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string value, out string result, out string validationErrorMessage)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

When I choose a value from select html component HandleChange is invoked and edit context is notified about the change, but when the event handler is invoked `Value` of `InputBase` holds old value, despite preceding `vm.Value = args.Value?.ToString();` assignment.

As a result when I first select a value, lets say a 'Rat' header remains empty, after second try when I select a 'Dog', 'Rat' appears in the header.

How do I read current value of an input in event handler? I have tried `CurrentValue` instead of `Value` but without success.

Comment: [Polite]  I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve here.  `InputComponent` isn't an input component, it's a simple display component, so why complicate things by using `InputBase`?  You aren't using the `InputSelect` for the select which seems the obvious thing to do.  If I know what you are trying to achieve, I can give you a sensible answer to your question.

Comment: In your `InputComponent`, try using `<h3>@CurrentValue</h3>` and delete all the code of `OnInitialized`. Is this what you want?

Comment: @FelipeCostaGualberto - Why does that work? There's no `input` in `InputComponent`  setting `CurrentValueAsString`, so nothing setting `CurrentValue`.

Comment: `InputComponent` inherits from `InputBase` - it is a complex class with lots of funcionalities and integration with the cascaded EditContext. See here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/InputBase.cs

Comment: @FelipeCostaGualberto - It is simplification of rather complicated flow. Instead of select I am using a web component written in javascript, therefore I cannot use InputSelect and InputComponent is an anouther javascript component that emits javascript events.